# Let's talk about list question cleanup 

Tags: discussion, cleanup

After some discussion on chat, we're realized the site has several list questions with many answers, mostly from the early days of the site.

Let's post candidate questions as community wiki answers to this thread, like this:

> **Question**
>
> - Problems
> - Suggested cleanup actions: Deletion, editing, combining answers, whichever.

That second line is what people will vote on - agreement or disagreement to your suggestion action on the question.

Please vote up or down, and use the comments to discuss. Are these truly list questions? Can they be edited so they're of more value to the site? If you like one of these and want it to stick around, let's hear why.

Comment: Mods, please feel free to make this CW if you think that's appropriate.

Comment: [Questions with more than 10 answers](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A11)

Answer (score 3):

[What do you do to make positive you remember your water bottle?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/507/what-do-you-do-to-make-positive-you-remember-your-water-bottle)

- This is a chatty, forum-style question.
- Candidate for closure.

Comment: Closed as recommended

Answer (score 3):

[What's your most useful cycle accessory?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/573/whats-your-most-useful-cycle-accessory)

- This is a chatty, forum-style question.
- Any unique answers can go to the [Terminology Index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index), then we delete this. It's not referenced in that many places, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

[What do you wish someone had told you before your first commute?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-do-you-wish-someone-had-told-you-before-your-first-commute)

- This has 31 answers that go across 2 pages, it's a bit of a mess. It's also kinda chatty.
- Maybe edit into fewer answers?

Comment: This is now at 33 answers, and I'd say "kinda chatty" is an understatement. :)

Answer (score 2):

### https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/recommended-good-value-cycle-lights-for-commute/1479#1479

- Big unmaintainable list
- Candidate for closure

Comment: Closed the question

Answer (score 2):

[Bicycling Apps for Android](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/bicycling-apps-for-android)

- It is a big list. It's slightly more maintainable than "Recommended Good Value Cycle Lights for Commute" because new Android apps aren't released quite as frequently, but it still seems destined to become outdated.
- Candidate for closure.

Comment: Question closed.

Answer (score 2):

[What are the most useful or interesting cycling-related websites or blogs?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-are-the-most-useful-or-interesting-cycling-related-websites-or-blogs)

- Chatty forum-style question AND a big unmaintainable list
- Candidate for closure

Comment: And now it's closed.

Answer (score 2):

[Most Crucial Gear/ Accessories for a (Road) Cycling Beginner?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4390/most-crucial-gear-accessories-for-a-road-cycling-beginner)

- Chatty question specifically asking for subjective responses
- Candidate for closure

Answer (score 2):

[Book Recommendation: Training](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/book-recommendation-training/10681)

- A list of books, which will always become outdated as new books are published. It is also impossible to come to any agreement on what the "best" book is.
- Candidate for closure.

Comment: Agreed. I voted to close last year, but that vote has since expired.

Answer (score 1):

[Best chain lubricant for road bikes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3/best-chain-lubricant-for-road-bikes)

- This is an obvious list question, since there's no single answer that summarizes it.
- I suggest deleting this and asking a question more along the lines of "What are the advantages and disadvantages of different kinds of lube for road bikes?"

Comment: Deleted as recommended

Answer (score 1):

[What tips do you have for making temporary “get me home” repairs?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/what-tips-do-you-have-for-making-temporary-get-me-home-repairs)

- Chatty open-ended question
- Candidate for closure

Answer (score 1):

[What is a good iPhone app for bikers?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-is-a-good-iphone-app-for-bikers/10749)

- A big list, which is difficult to maintain as new apps are added and as new versions of apps are released.
- Candidate for closure

Answer (score 0):

[What advanced cycling skills are useful for a commuter or city rider?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/what-advanced-cycling-skills-are-useful-for-a-commuter-or-city-rider)

- Chatty forum-style question
- Candidate for closure

Answer (score 0):

[Is there an easy to use app for tracking my cycling performance? (iOS or Android)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/is-there-an-easy-to-use-app-for-tracking-my-cycling-performance-ios-or-android)

- Potential to become a big unmaintainable list. Also a duplicate of [What is a good iPhone app for bikers?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-is-a-good-iphone-app-for-bikers/10749) and [Bicycling apps for Android](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/bicycling-apps-for-android)
- Candidate for closure